# How to do this just as elegantly in Python?

Tags: bash, shell, python, ruby

I'm just learning Python. One thing I hope to use Python for is Linux shell scripting. I've been studying some examples and practicing by converting my bash scripts to Python.

I just spent a few hours converting one of my bash scripts to Python and I was very disappointed with my resulting code. It was much more verbose and syntactically cluttered. It was certainly not concise and tight like the bash script I started with.

Then I stumbled across this (unrelated) Ruby script. Wow. It seems to give direct access to the shell, unlike Python which has a layer or two between the language and the shell.

```
#! /usr/bin/ruby
MAX_TIME_SINCE_START = 1800
begin
  curr_time = Time.new.to_i
  kslideshow_processes_list = `pgrep kslideshow.kss`.split("\n")
  kslideshow_processes_list.each { |kslideshow_process|
      kslideshow_process.strip!
      ps_result = `ps -p #{kslideshow_process} -o lstart`
      process_start_date = `ps -p #{kslideshow_process} -o
lstart`.split("\n")[1].strip
      get_date_command = "date -d \"#{process_start_date}\" +\"%s\""
      kslideshow_start_time = `#{get_date_command}`.to_i
      time_since_started = curr_time - kslideshow_start_time
      if time_since_started MAX_TIME_SINCE_START
          system( "kill #{kslideshow_process}" )
      end
  }
  sleep MAX_TIME_SINCE_START
end while true
```

This is the kind of code I was hoping would result from my switch from bash script to Python. Is it possible in Python to write shell scripts so cleanly?

It would be very educational for me to see the above code converted to Python by someone who knows what they are doing.

I don't intend to start a Ruby vs. Python discussion. I simply want to see how cleanly the above task can be implemented in Python by someone who knows more Python than I do. Is that a fair question for this site? Thanks

Comment: As an aside, that is *terrible* practise (regardless of being in Ruby). Arbitrarily injecting syntax into the shell is a good way to create gaping security holes, or inadvertently destroy your system.

Comment: That's got to be the worst Ruby script I've ever seen.

Comment: This is bad practice. If you're going to write a script, you should stick to that language as much as possible, not mix multiple languages. And that is a pretty terrible ruby script, but as for why: 1) `loop do` is the proper way, not `begin ... end while true`. 2) It's using the `date` command to parse a time when ruby is perfectly capable of doing that itself. 3) multi-line blocks with `{}` are just bad form, multi-line should use `do ... end`. 4) shells out for `kill` as well when ruby has `Process.kill`. 5) `if time_since_started MAX_TIME_SINCE_START`, where is the keyword (`and`/`or`)?.

Comment: Everyone has gone on about how it's a bad idea to do this, but I want to address the difficulty of managing external processes in `python` vs `ruby`. The `ruby` subprocess syntax borrowed from `perl` is easy but it's considerably less powerful and flexible than Python's `subprocess` module. Ruby has equivalents, but it's not backticks and `system()`.

Comment: FWIW, Ruby’s [ShellWords.escape](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html#method-c-escape) would help a lot with the security issues here.

Comment: Be getting used some tasks like shell interaction or regular expressions handling are not so straightforward in Python as in Ruby. It's solved in  general way through modules from standard library, Python just lacks direct syntax support.

Comment: I wouldn't call that Ruby elegant by any stretch; it's hardly even Ruby since all the work is done via shell subprocesses. I think the root of your question is "does Python have syntactic sugar like Ruby's backticks for executing a subshell and capturing the results in a list", and the short answer is no; you have to use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: Also note that this isn't getting "direct access to the shell" in any way. Every shell command is a subprocess, which is very expensive and is run in isolation. The code you pasted here would be much shorter, cleaner, and more efficient written in pure Bash (or some other shell language), or written in pure Ruby/Python (without any of the unnecessary shell commands).

Comment: @JimStewart - yes, one of my questions was about "syntactic sugar like Ruby's backticks". Thanks for making that clear. And you also cleared up my misconception about how the subprocesses are working here. I have read about this, but I mistakeningly thought Ruby was doing something "magical" when in fact I should have known better.

Comment: @DavidUnric - You said, "some tasks like shell interaction or regular expressions handling are not so straightforward in Python as in Ruby." I was hoping they were as clean in Python as in Ruby. Anyway, I'm committed to learning Python for now. And others have pointed out the advantages of Python's `subprocess`. I'll use that approach.

Comment: @MountainX I see no problem here. It's all about experience, personal preferences and current opportunities. Later you'll see the differences between most of programming languages are rather superficial and that's especially valid for Python vs. Ruby debates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring the bad ideas and ways you could poke your own eye out.. an example of the more efficient way to open a another process in python is as follows...

```
process = subprocess.Popen([MyCommand, parameter1, "parameter 2"], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                              stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr = process.communicate()
return_code = process.poll()
```

Doing things with popen is a little bit more overhead than some other languages, but it offers a lot of versatility that no other scripting language I know of offers like getting output from many many processes live.

Answer (score 2):

You can IMO do this at least as elegant as in Ruby by using the [`plumbum`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum) package. There are  ways to optimize away system calls (e.g. using `dateutils` to convert from a date format, or using `psutils`), but that would no longer be a comparison of calling system utilities (I hope I got the logic from the Ruby example correct):

```
from time import time, sleep
from plumbum.cmd import pgrep, ps, date, kill

MAX_TIME_SINCE_START = 5 # 1800

while True:
   curr_time = time()
   for kslideshow_process in pgrep("gimp").split():
      print kslideshow_process
   process_start_date = ps("-p",  kslideshow_process, "-o", "lstart"
                           ).split("\n")[1].strip()
   kslideshow_start_time = int(date("-d", process_start_date, '+%s'))
   print kslideshow_start_time
   time_since_started = curr_time - kslideshow_start_time
   if time_since_started > MAX_TIME_SINCE_START:
      kill([kslideshow_process])
   sleep(MAX_TIME_SINCE_START)
```

You can import **any** commandline program using `from plumbum.cmd import ...` and it is automatically available as a function that takes the commandline arguments as parameters.
You can also make chains of commands:

```
chain = ls["-a"] | grep["-v", "\\.py"] | wc["-l"]
result = chain()
```

so there is far less often need for intermediate variables to carry results from one subshell to another.